# Generating cyclic group for Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption

Tags: symmetric, pairings, group-theory

I am doing Project under the topic CP-ABE.I need to generate a symmetric bilinear group Go of prime order p and with generator g...Then how to choose random elements from Zp....kindly anyone help me...Is it possible to do this with Java?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about programming and mathematics without any direct connection to cryptography.

Comment: we have used this http://www.charm-crypto.com/Main.html but it is written in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries allowing to do that:

- [PBC](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/): C library
- [JPBC](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/#.VNMkeZ2G8ys) : Java library

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sir i have included jpbc...but i cannot resolve import it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pairing.DefaultCurveParameters;could u help me

Comment: I have never used it. I cannot help you.